# Is there a formula for the MGF of $Y=g(X)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable with cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_X$ and probability density function (DF) $f_X$. Suppose $g\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a differentiable, strictly monotonic function. Then it can be proved that $Y=g(X)$ is a continuous random variable with CDF
$$F_Y(y)=F_X(g^{-1}(y)),$$
and DF
$$f_Y(y)=\bigg|\frac{1}{g^\prime(g^{-1}(y))}\bigg|f_X(g^{-1}(y)).$$

Is there a similar formula, in general, for the moment generating function (MGF) of $Y$?

I thought we might find it as follows:

$$M_Y(t)=E[e^{tg(X)}]\stackrel{?}{=}\int_\Bbb{R}e^{tg(x)}f_Y(x)\,dx,$$
but my attempts to simplify this integral (in general) and get it in the form of $M_X(t)$ have not succeeded, and only left me more confused.

Comment: Close: That may have been a typo, but just to be sure: $M_Y(t) ~=~ \mathsf E[e^{t~g(X)}]  ~=~ \int_\Bbb{R}\mathsf e^{t~g(x)}~f_{\color{red}X}(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Comment: That's about as general as it gets without specifying the distribution.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh thanks, that was not a typo, but I see my mistake. I had tried to apply the law of the unconscious statistician, i.e. $E(h(X))=\int h(x)f_X(x)\,dx$, where $h(x):=e^{t\,g(x)}$; but apparently got confused with which variable $h$ took and used the wrong DF.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I suppose the proviso with this is "when the integral converges": can the MGF of $Y$ not exist even when the MGF of $X$ does?